# How to find using json object using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a data in mongodb like below.

```
{
   "color":"gray",
   "object": {
       "name": "apple",
       "price": "2000",
       "qu" : "good"
   }
}
```

And I want to find this data using mongoose in nodejs.

```
  const result  = await findOne({color: "gray", object:{name:"apple"}})
```

But it doesn't give anything. How can I use find well to find inside of json object?
Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: `const result  = await findOne({color: "gray", "object.name":"apple" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const result  = await YourSchemaModelName.findOne({
                                                   "color": "gray", 
                                                   "object.name": { "$eq" : "apple"}
                                                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation to find nested objects

```
const result = await Model.find({ 
    "color": "gray",
    "object.name": "apple"
})
.limit(1)
```

FYI: I used .find() + .limit(1) rather than .findOne() for performance reasons

> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/difference-between-mongodbs-find-and-findone-calls

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
const result = await Model.findOne({color: "gray", "object.name":"apple" });
```